# Why does the synchronized wrapper for ArrayList not work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, arraylist

I have generated the proxy classes for a web service in Visual Studio with 'Add Web Reference'. The generated `RTWebService` class has a method `SetValueAsync`. I extended this class and added a `SetValueRequest` which keeps track of the requests and cancels all pending requests when an error occurs. With every request I store the `userState` object in an ArrayList I created as follows:

```
requests = ArrayList.Synchronized(new ArrayList());
```

I created a method:

```
public void CancelPendingRequests() {
  lock (requests.SyncRoot) {
    if (requests.Count > 0) {
      foreach (object request in requests) {
        this.CancelAsync(request);
      }
      requests.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

I call this method when a request returns on the `SetValueCompleted` event:

```
private void onRequestComplete(
    object sender, 
    Service.SetValueCompletedEventArgs args
) {
  lock (syncResponse) {
    if (args.Cancelled) {
      return;
    }

    if (args.UserState != null) {
      requests.Remove(args.UserState);
    }

    if (args.Error != null) {
      CancelPendingRequests();
    }
  }
}
```

To start a new request I call:

```
public void SetValueRequest(string tag, string value) {
  var request = new object();
  this.SetValueAsync(tag, value, request);
  requests.Add(request);
}
```

Everytime I make a request and at the same time a response returns with an error, I get a `TargetInvocationException` in the `CancelPendingRequests`. The inner exception is an `InvalidOperationException` on an ArrayList in the `CancelPendingRequests` method saying:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

So it seems `SetValueRequest` has modified the `requests` object while I was enumerating it. I thought this was impossible because I used the synchronized wrapper for ArrayList and use the SyncRoot to synchronize the enumeration. I'm a bit stuck on this so if anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I worked around the problem by removing the enumeration. I now use:

```
public void CancelPendingRequests() {
  lock (requests.SyncRoot) {
    if (requests.Count > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < requests.Count; i++) {
        this.CancelAsync(requests[i]);
      }
      requests.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to do the trick. I'm still a bit worried that this `lock (requests.SyncRoot)` didn't work on the enumeration so why would it work here? Anyway, I am now unable to reproduce the exception like i could before so I consider this problem as solved. I can't waste any more time on this.

**EDIT**

Forget my silly answer above. I was working on a project and needed to make progress. I tracked down the problem now:

So it appeared this bug was not multithreading related at all. All code was executed on the same thread, I didn't need those locks. The problem lies in the fact that I was canceling the requests in my enumeration. The `CancelAsync` method raises the `SetValueCompleted` event which in turn calls `requests.Remove`, thus modifying the requests inside the enumeration. I Learnt some pitfall with events today.

I solved the problem by enumerating over a local copy of the `requests` object which I created with the `ToArray` method.

```
public void CancelPendingRequests() 
  if (requests.Count > 0) {
    for (object request in requests.ToArray()) {
      this.CancelAsync(request);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you're code is still broken. the for won't shout loudly if you change the list while iterating on it, but you will still have race conditions bugs.

Comment: Indeed that's what I meant, the question is **why**? Why is the list changed even though I synchronize it with `requests.SyncRoot`. I'm not removing items so this one doesn't break.

Comment: 1. the exception thrown clearly means you're wrong, the list is being manipulated while you are iterating. 2. ArrayList.Synchronized only syncs individual actions, not logical transactions. getting the list's enumerator is syncd, but once you touch the list, all former enumerators are broken. there is a way to fix this within ArrayList, you can do this through the SyncRoot, but you shouldn't, because it's a broken mechanism

Answer (score 3):

1. never use SyncRoot it's inherently broken. (if you share the list you just invite a deadlock)
2. Don't use ArrayList, it should be marked "Deprecated".
3. ArrayList.Synchronized return's something that works more slowly but is **not** thread safe, i.e. it's not thread safe during a set of operations.
4. you can either use something from System.Collection.Concurrent, or use ReaderWriterLockSlim

Comment: I'm developing for .NET 2.0 for this project, I believe System.Collection.Concurrent or ReaderWriterLockSlim are 4.0? I solved it differently: I copy the requests ArrayList with `ToArray()`.

Comment: @Jan- 1. System.Collection.Concurrent is only in .Net 4 , or in Reactive Extensions. 2. ReaderWriterLockSlim  is in .Net 3.5 though. 3. ToArray() is not thread safe either...

Comment: Why does msdn state that all operations (except for enumeration) on ArrayList are thread safe if called through the synchronized wrapper? I just effectively removed the enumeration on the ArrayList and did it on an array copy.

Comment: List.ToArray uses Array.Copy which as i recall is not thread safe. i.e. it enumerates over the list...

Comment: But Array.Copy is wrapped in a lock on SyncRoot, like every method. So they are synchronized. That's the whole point of ArrayList.Synchronized isn't it? Anyway, I think I found the problem. requests.Remove was called in the eventhandler, which in turn got invoked on CancelAsync. Because they are nested the lock on SyncRoot had no effect and the list was modified.

Comment: i strongly suggest you download the BCL sources, or take a look with a reflector... ArrayList.Synchronized does NOT do what you are expecting

Comment: I strongly suggest you spread your knowledge about what ArrayList.Synchronized does differently than what the manual says, might be helpful for a lot of people (including me). Perhaps you can update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding a local variable to your CancelPendingRequests method for each request object like this:

```
  public void CancelPendingRequests() {
  lock (requests.SyncRoot) 
  {
      if (requests.Count > 0) 
      {
          foreach (object request in requests) 
          {
          object currentRequest = request; //Add this
          this.CancelAsync(currentRequest);
          }
          requests.Clear();
       }
  }
```

}

Comment: I thought it might have been related to the Access Modified Closure error I have seen before.  Don't know why it wouldn't work though. Maybe someone can give a good explanation. Good luck.